# Is it possible to merge two detect.tflite files into one detect.tflite File?

Tags: tensorflow

I have trained Two models and generated their detect.tflite files successfully, I need to know that , Is there any way to merge both detect.tflite file so that resulting one detect file can be used in android/ios application?

Answer (score 0):

I did quiet decent research on this and came to conclusion that two .tflite file cannot be merged, however one can combine datasets and retrain model and generate new .tflite file which can do job of both previous .tflite files